# Raspberry Pi libcamerasrc and GStreamer RTSP server

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, rtsp-server

I have a Raspberry Pi 4, 32 bit OS; GStreamer 1.18, Arducam 64MP Hawkeye camera.
I'm trying to create a RTSP stream using GStreamer.    I'm using VLC on a secondary computer to verify the stream.

I built GStreamer RTSP Server (test-launch) successfully demonstrated by:

```
./test-launch --gst-debug=3 '( videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=I420,framerate=10/1 ! queue ! x264enc ! queue ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )'
```

The above pipeline works well - no warnings, errors etc.   So, I would think I could just substitute the test source w/ libcamerasrc.

```
 ./test-launch --gst-debug=3 '( libcamerasrc ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,format=I420,framerate=10/1 ! queue ! x264enc ! queue ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 )'

0:00:00.002252699  2750  0x130f680 WARN         GST_PERFORMANCE gstbuffer.c:496:_priv_gst_buffer_initialize: No 64-bit atomic int defined for this platform/toolchain!
stream ready at rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/test
[2:28:52.686563784] [2752]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:297 libcamera v0.0.0+4367-ad9428b4
[2:28:52.726008528] [2753]  WARN CameraSensorProperties camera_sensor_properties.cpp:261 No static properties available for 'arducam_64mp'
[2:28:52.726127063] [2753]  WARN CameraSensorProperties camera_sensor_properties.cpp:263 Please consider updating the camera sensor properties database
[2:28:52.818015917] [2753]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:444 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/arducam_64mp@1a to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media1
0:00:04.291297745  2750 0xf5d420e8 FIXME                default gstutils.c:4025:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<libcamerasrc0:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
[2:28:52.850803303] [2758]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1033 configuring streams: (0) 1280x720-YUV420
[2:28:52.852476027] [2753]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:572 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/arducam_64mp@1a - Selected sensor format: 1280x720-SRGGB10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1280x720-pRAA
0:00:24.149406551  2750  0x14c7100 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:3576:wait_preroll: failed to preroll pipeline
0:00:24.149480328  2750  0x14c7100 WARN               rtspmedia rtsp-media.c:3946:gst_rtsp_media_prepare: failed to preroll pipeline
0:00:24.665921409  2750  0x14c7100 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:1087:find_media: client 0x14c1a08: can't prepare media
0:00:24.666612957  2750  0x14c7100 ERROR             rtspclient rtsp-client.c:3346:handle_describe_request: client 0x14c1a08: no media
```

I'm assuming my understanding of the source is wrong.   Has anyone created a GStreamer based RTSP stream with Arducam 64 MP Hawkeye camera on a Raspberry Pi 4?    (I'm going to consume the stream w/ NVIDIA Deepstream.)

Comment: You might be able to get more response at [raspberrypi.se].

Comment: The camera may not support I420 output format.

Comment: Per @FlorianZwoch comment, running `gst-device-monitor-1.0` may help id that

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual - found a lot more information here:
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/RPi_Camera_(I)

The native libcamera-vid driver app provides more than enough functionality that I abandoned GStreamer for simple RTSP streaming.  The documentation cited above also explains the correct way to provide a source in a GStreamer pipeline.   I'm assuming using the libcamera driver is faster than the overhead of a full GStreamer pipeline so I am sticking with libcamera.

Here is my final libcamera pipeline:

```
libcamera-vid -n --framerate=2 -t 0 --denoise=cdn_off --autofocus-mode=manual --lens-position=0 --level=4.2 --width=1248 --height=384 --inline -o - | cvlc stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/stream1}' :demux=h264
```

This works but not very well.     The performance was generally lousy.    Conclusion:  awesome camera, awesome driver but not enough encoding performance on the RPI.    I did not fine tune this pipeline as a result.   I didn't get the manual focus to work as expected.   I also abandoned the ROI functionality (which would be useful for Deepstream).    I went back to using NVIDIA Jetsons.   I hope Arducam makes this camera compatible with Jetsons like their IMX477 products.

If anyone can recommend how to improve the performance and stability on the above DAG, please reply.    I am impressed with the camera and would like to make better use of it.